# Load/Unload Cycle Count using S.M.A.R.T and WMI

Tags: c#, windows-7, wmi, disk-smart

In an attempt to develop a hard disk analytic tool, I'm trying to get the value of Load/Unload cycle count from my hard disk's S.M.A.R.T data, I'm wondering if anyone knows how to do this. 
What I'm trying:

1. I'm searching the WMI `MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData` class data where attribute number [193](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) is what i need (the attribute representing load/unload cycle count)
2. The data I'm getting looks like

[image]

I think I'm close, the data in red is the same as what Everest Home edition is showing when i run it, ideally i would want the last part  which is  (attribute called data)

[image]

Method for collecting this data:

```
static void doStuff()
{
    try
    {

        byte TEMPERATURE_ATTRIBUTE = 193;

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData");
        //loop through all the hard disks
        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            byte[] arrVendorSpecific = (byte[])queryObj.GetPropertyValue("VendorSpecific");

            int tempIndex = Array.IndexOf(arrVendorSpecific, TEMPERATURE_ATTRIBUTE);
            Console.WriteLine("HDD TEMP: " + arrVendorSpecific[tempIndex + 5].ToString());

            foreach (byte dat in arrVendorSpecific)
            {
                Console.Write(dat.ToString() + " ");
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err) { Console.WriteLine(err.Message); }
}
```

P.S. this method works for collecting the HDD's temperature (that's what the `Console.WriteLine("HDD TEMP: " + arrVendorSpecific[tempIndex + 5].ToString());` line is all about but I'm not sure why its tempIndex+5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code which you are using is not correct, because you are using a secuencial search (Array.IndexOf) to find the S.M.A.R.T `Attribute ID` (you can have false positives because that value can match with another in the array), the ID of these attibutes has an fixed position inside of an documented structure ([`SMART Attribute Overview`](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2005/e05171r0-ACS-SMARTAttributes_Overview.pdf)).

**SMART Attribute Table**

```
Offset  Length  Description
        (bytes) 
0         2      SMART structure version (this is vendor-specific)
2         12     Attribute entry 1
2+(12)    12     Attribute entry 2
. . .
2+(12*29) 12     Attribute entry 30
```

**Entry in the Attribute Table**

[image]

from here you can write a code to search the location of each attribute and get the values which you are looking for

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Attribute
        {
            public byte AttributeID;
            public ushort Flags;
            public byte Value;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
            public byte[] VendorData;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Attribute AtributeInfo;
                ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\WMI", "localhost"), null);
                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT VendorSpecific FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
                byte LoadCycleCount = 0xC1;
                int Delta  = 12;
                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    byte[] VendorSpecific = (byte[])WmiObject["VendorSpecific"];
                    for (int offset = 2; offset < VendorSpecific.Length; )
                    {
                        if (VendorSpecific[offset] == LoadCycleCount)
                        {

                            IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
                            try
                            {
                                buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Delta);
                                Marshal.Copy(VendorSpecific, offset, buffer, Delta);
                                AtributeInfo = (Attribute)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(Attribute));
                                Console.WriteLine("AttributeID {0}", AtributeInfo.AttributeID);
                                Console.WriteLine("Flags {0}", AtributeInfo.Flags);
                                Console.WriteLine("Value {0}", AtributeInfo.Value);
                                Console.WriteLine("Value {0}", BitConverter.ToString(AtributeInfo.VendorData));
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                                {
                                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
                                }
                            }                                                
                        }
                        offset += Delta;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```